# Can't Install Firebase Messaging Package

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to install Firebase Messaging to an old flutter project but I get this error message

> Because firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.0+1 and firebase_admob >=0.9.1 <0.10.0-dev.1 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.2+1, firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 is incompatible with firebase_admob >=0.9.1 <0.10.0-dev.1.
> So, because AppName depends on both firebase_admob ^0.9.3+2 and firebase_messaging ^7.0.3, version solving failed.

pubspec.yaml file

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  sqflite: ^1.2.1
  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.4
  network_to_file_image: ^2.2.8
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+2
  firebase_database: ^3.1.3
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  share: ^0.6.3+6
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.1.1+3
  auto_direction: ^0.0.4+1
  sliding_up_panel: ^1.0.0
  draggable_scrollbar: ^0.0.4
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+2
  provider: ^4.3.2
  pdf: ^1.10.0
  printing: ^3.5.0
  flutter_sms: ^2.0.0+1
  timeline_tile: ^1.0.0
```

anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It's more likely somebody can help if you show (the dependencies from) your `pubspec.yaml`. Also please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it drastically increases the chances of getting help on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try removing the version number after the colon ":" from the three sdks.

firebase_messaging:
firebase_admob:
firebase_core:

then run pub get again

Comment: after doing that
I can Pub get without any problems

Comment: but when runing the app I get this error :
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzbb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.firebase.messaging.zzf`.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Answer (score 1):

The `firebase_messaging` and the `firebase_admob` package depend on different versions of the `firebase_core` package.

| package | required `firebase_core` version |
| --- | --- |
| `firebase_messaging` | ^0.5.0+1 |
| `firebase_admob` | ^0.4.2+1 |

You can't have both versions. You need to use versions of these two packages that require the same `firebase_core` version. The newest versions of these two packages require 0.7.0:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/pubspec.yaml
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_admob/pubspec.yaml

Answer (score -1):

Set Firebase packages to the versions given in the table at this link

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/

Thanks to this answer on Github issues

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4650#issuecomment-760905814

Comment: Even though adding latest versions of all packages does not work. It still gives me a dependency error and it does not solve the problem.